# Material-ui-pickers - how to set options? I need to allow awareOfUnicodeTokens

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Can somebody help please?
I have a problem - I'm formating date from '2019-03-24' to '24.03.2019' and sending it to Material-ui-pickers datepicker. 
As a result I'm getting this error

```
Uncaught RangeError: `options.awareOfUnicodeTokens` must be set to `true` to use `YYYY` token; see: https://git.io/fxCyr
```

**dateInputFormat** recieves current format. My code follows

```
import React, { FC } from 'react';
import { MuiPickersUtilsProvider, DatePicker, DatePickerProps } from 'material-ui-pickers';
import 'date-fns';
import DateFnsUtils from '@date-io/date-fns';
import { useRepresentation } from '../../hooks/representation';

type Props = {
  children?: never
} & DatePickerProps;


const InputDate: FC<Props> = (props) => {
  const { dateInputFormat } = useRepresentation();

  return (
    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
      <DatePicker
        {...props}
        format={dateInputFormat}
      />
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
  );
};

export default InputDate;
```

Just don't understand where to add that option.
Help please :)

Answer (score 0):

The only one option is to override the default methods of [date-io](https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/date-io) date-fns implementation. You can follow [this guide](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/guides/formats) to proceed.

But the recommended option will be to just **not use unicode** tokens. Instead use the recommended by date-fns. [Read](https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/blob/master/docs/unicodeTokens.md#popular-mistakes) about popular mistakes.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the help!